# What is God's throne like?

Tags: heaven, throne-of-god

What is God's throne like? I have heard many things such as, his throne is made of Gold, his throne is made of celestial sapphire stone, that his throne is white, that his throne is technological and he uses it as a throne/vehicle.

Are there any references to descriptions of the Throne of God in the Bible (including deuterocanonicals if necessary) and/or from early Patristic Fathers?

Answer (score 4):

There are several references to God's Throne within the Bible:

In Matthew 5:34 Jesus tells us Heaven is God's throne

> "But I say to you, Do not take an oath at all, either by heaven, for it is the throne of God"

This recalls God's opening statement in Isaiah 66:1

> Thus says the Lord: “Heaven is my throne,and the earth is my footstool; what is the house that you would build for me, and what is the place of my rest?"

Other references to the Throne of God can be found in 2 Chronicles 18:18; Psalm 11:4; Hebrews 8:1; 12:2; Revelation 1:4; 3:21; 4:2; and many other verses in the Bible.

In Revelation Chapter 4 we get a description of the Throne from John:

> ...2 At once I was in the Spirit, and behold, **a throne stood in heaven, with one seated on the throne. 3 And he who sat there had the appearance of jasper and carnelian, and around the throne was a rainbow that had the appearance of an emerald.**...**5 From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings[a] and peals of thunder, and before the throne were burning seven torches of fire, which are the seven spirits of God, 6 and before the throne there was as it were a sea of glass, like crystal.**
>
> **And around the throne, on each side of the throne, are four living creatures, full of eyes in front and behind**: 7 the first living creature like a lion, the second living creature like an ox, the third living creature with the face of a man, and the fourth living creature like an eagle in flight. 8 **And the four living creatures, each of them with six wings, are full of eyes all around and within, and day and night they never cease to say,** “Holy, holy, holy, is the Lord God Almighty, who was and is and is to come!”
>
> **9 And whenever the living creatures give glory and honor and thanks to him who is seated on the throne, who lives forever and ever, 10 the twenty-four elders fall down before him who is seated on the throne and worship him who lives forever and ever. They cast their crowns before the throne**...

So we have a description of the surroundings, but what about the throne? We find that in Revelation Chapter 20:11:

> **Then I saw a Great White Throne, and Him who was sitting on it.** The Earth and its skies (heavens) fled away from His presence, and there was no place found for them to hide.

Of course, this would depend on whether one takes the translation as literal or symbolic. Literally the Throne would be white, as described, with all the happening around it. Symbolically, the Throne is symbolic - and God's throne is just Heaven / nothing because He is a spirit.

Answer (score 1):

There are some truths we must understand, before answering your question.

> Genesis 1:1  In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

From this Scripture three things become evident.

1. God existed before anything material.
2. Where God existed prior to creation (for lack of a better term) we will call the Spiritual Realm. For some of us that is what we consider to be Heaven.
3. God's creation exists within the Spiritual realm, and let's just name it the material realm.

With these in mind let's look at some things we learn from the Bible itself.

> Matthew 4:17  From that time Jesus began to preach, and to say, Repent: for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.

So what did Jesus mean when he said the Kingdom of heaven is at hand.

From David Guziks commentary on the whole Bible.

> 1. (17) Jesus' message: Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.
>      From that time Jesus began to preach and to say, "Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand."
>
> > a. Repent: The gospel Jesus preached began the same place that the gospel John preached began - with a call to repentance (Mat. 3:2). In fact, since Jesus waited until John had been put in prison (Mat. 4:12), He probably saw Himself as picking up where John left off. But Jesus would go further than John ever did, because John announced the coming of the Messiah, and Jesus is the Messiah.
> >
> > b. For the kingdom of heaven is at hand: Some people make elaborate distinctions between the kingdom of heaven and the kingdom of God. There actually seems to be no difference at all, especially in light of the Jewish custom of often not even naming God directly, but referring to Him by the place where He lives heaven - a custom that Matthew, a Jew writing to Jews, often employs.

If we agree with this commentary, it must then refer to that which we have named the Spiritual realm.

So now to address your question about descriptions of the throne of God.

> Matthew 23:22  And he that shall swear by heaven, sweareth by the throne of God, and by him that sitteth thereon.
>
> Hebrews 12:2  Looking unto Jesus the author and finisher of our faith; who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising the shame, and is set down at the right hand of the throne of God.

Since we have established that that where God lives is a Spiritual realm, things in the Spiritual realm would have no material components. So if God were giving a illustration of his throne he would of necessity have to portray it in some material manner. That would only be possible if it were presented as something dazzling, otherwise it would only have some materialistic value.

It must be just as hard for God to commune with us as it is for we as adults to commune with very small children, possibly even harder.